# Multi-page form submition using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a requirement on converting jsp-springmvc application into html-angularjs-spring .

One requirement is .. I have a form which is having multiple page (3) ('Next' button) and finally submit the data to DB. There is a 'previous' button also in the page . Basically I should be able to go back and forth to edit .

Is there any special way in angularjs to achieve this .Any example ???

Comment: try using services in to share the data & in you submit button controller try to assign all the data in to an object or varable whatever it may be and post it to your db in that way it is possible to send the data to DB

Comment: Angular is for `SPA`.. Do not think about `conventional-page-redirection` with angular..

Comment: Just save all your data to a factory as long as you aren't refreshing the page. If you are refreshing the page then save it to local storage and reload it when the page reloads.

Answer (score -1):

Have you considered using a multi step form plugin ?

As far as I remember, I used https://github.com/troch/angular-multi-step-form to create a 3 step wizard to generate a custom bundle for a customer.

Have a look at this ( and other multi step form plugins :) ) !